# Linq query to get rows between two dates having repetitive dates and group them

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `SQL` table like this.

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ Id ║              Date              ║  Col3   ║   Col4   ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    ║ ....... ║ ........ ║
║  2 ║ 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    ║ ....... ║ ........ ║
║  3 ║ 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    ║ ....... ║ ........ ║
║  4 ║ 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    ║ ....... ║ ........ ║
║  5 ║ 2018-11-01 00:00:00.0000000    ║ ....... ║ ........ ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

I want to select these rows such that I specify a start date and an end date, and the response is formatted as follows, if i give the start date as 2018-10-31 and end date as 2018-10-30,

```
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
| Id |              Date              |  Col3   |   Col4   |
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  2 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  3 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  4 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
```

I tried using the following but it do not return anything. I dont know if my query is wrong.

```
[HttpGet("GetClamped")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIntegration([FromQuery] string start, [FromQuery] string end)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-mm-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-mm-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var integration = await _context.Integrations.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Date > startDate && t.Date < endDate);

    if (integration == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(integration);
}
```

And if I want to group similar dates together, how can I do that? 
Eg:

```
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
| Id |              Date              |  Col3   |   Col4   |
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  3 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  2 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
|  4 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000    | ....... | ........ |
+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So the entries with `Id=1` and `Id=2` somehow "belong" together in your logic? How do you know that? Is it _only_ because they have subsequent `Id`? -- The second one should be the equivalent of `[...] ORDER BY Date, Id` in SQL or `someQueriableOrEnumerable.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ThenBy(item => item.Id)` in LINQ.

Comment: If you have a 404 error then you probably call wrong action name, check the namings, you function has a HttpGet name, try to use other one

Comment: Use the DateTime Date property which truncates the dates to midnight.  A DateTime is a number with the integer portion the number of days from 1/1/01 and the fractional portion of the number is X/24 hours.  Use Date truncates the fraction portion of the number.  So use GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date)

Comment: Item Id is not relevant for my query. after selecting the data I can anyway access it. I thought my `linq` is wrong.

Comment: @NishanChathuranga, what datatype of date column in database and same for your  model's property?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities of why you get the 404 error, i.e.:

1. The arguments passed are in invalid format ex. yyyy-dd-mm instead of yyyy-mm-dd
2. The context does not connect to the database with data or there is no data at all. Try to do the following: `var integration = _context.Integrations.ToList();`

To get a range of items you can't use the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` function. For that use `Where`

In order to group elements - there's another function `GroupBy`. You can find more functions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Query your DB with

```
_context.Integrations.FindAll(t => t.Date > startDate && t.Date < endDate).OrderBy(t => t.Date);
```

Hope it helps!